# how can I prevent opening the default option in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

I want to open custom pop up using pressing CTRL+F but in IE it opens find option also. How can I prevent that find option?

Comment: Don't have IE to create/test something for you but I wanted to mention that replacing the CTRL-F function is not usually appreciated by your users.
I've experienced it a few times and its always slower and less reliable than the browser search I'm used to.

Comment: @ChristiaanMaks: Indeed. Just about the only use-case I can see not irritating people is when typing in an online document editor (like Google Docs) where Ctrl+F opens a seach feature that works with the document (and in fact Google Docs does that). Just about anything else will irritate people. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You hook `keydown` and prevent the default action:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && (e.which || e.keyCode) == 70) { // 70 = F key
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("You pressed Ctrl+F");
    }
}, false);
```

```html
Click here to focus the document, then press Ctrl+F
```

This works on IE11 as well as Chrome and Firefox, with Ctrl+F. You can't override some other keys, such as Ctrl+T.

Comment: I am using IE 11 but still I am getting the find option

Comment: @Ashish: You need to ensure the document has focus in order to receive keydown events on it. That's the reason for the "Click here to focus the document" text. (Be sure you click [Run code snippet] and then focus the actual snippet document, not the code quoted above it.)